# Bind save-button to DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, button, datatable

I am trying to find out, if it's possible to bind a "Save-Button" to the Changes of a DataTable, example:

A) Save-Button is disabled

B) User changes something in the datagridview (bound to a datatable)

C) Now the Button should be enabled

I know I can do this manually by listening to cell-value-changed events etc. but it would be really nice to directly bind it to the datatable.

This is as far as I got

```
           Binding binding = new Binding("Enabled", _myDataTable.GetChanges(), "Rows.Count");
         _cmdSave.DataBindings.Add(binding);
```

I know that this is not gonna work, because `Rows.Count` is an Integer not an Boolean *and* especially because I always run in trouble because `_myDataTable.GetChanges()` returns `null` if no changes were made.

Anyone got a solution for this, or a little trick that's doing something like that?

**Edit:** As I figured out, the main problem is because `myDataTable.GetChanges()` return `null` - any solution here? A `binding.DataSourceNullValue=false;` doesn't change anything. I really don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to convert the value using [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse.aspx) event.

Good luck!

Comment: Pointed me to the right direction, but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Actually I didn't try it with a `DataTable`, I just tried it with two `TextBox`. that's all. Try it and inform me if your problem isn't  solved

Comment: The event is never fired, because in the moment `_form.ShowDialog(_parentForm)` is called, I am getting a null-exception